# Ruby souce code: rb_define_alias() vs method redefined with different name

Tags: ruby

Looking at Ruby source code, I am wondering if there is a difference between defining an alias, as in the case of Array#inspect and Array#to_s,

```
rb_define_method(rb_cArray, "inspect", rb_ary_inspect, 0);
rb_define_alias(rb_cArray,  "to_s", "inspect");
```

and redefining a method using a different name, as in the case of Array#collect and Array#map.

```
rb_define_method(rb_cArray, "collect", rb_ary_collect, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cArray, "map", rb_ary_collect, 0);
```

https://github.com/h4dex/ruby/blob/master/array.c

rb_define_method and rb_define_alias are defined here, but I don't know enough to follow:
https://github.com/h4dex/ruby/blob/49995e8ed107b14eaac382f45347db2f1fff2a9e/class.c

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, here are the two chains of method calls:

```
rb_define_alias()
  |
  V
rb_alias()
  |
  V
rb_method_entry_set()
  |
  V
method_added()
  |
  V
CALL_METHOD_HOOK()
```

---

```
rb_define_method()
  |
  V
rb_add_method_cfunc()
  |
  V
rb_add_method()
  |
  V
method_added()
  |
  V
CALL_METHOD_HOOK()
```

It's possible that one of the methods was added to the language at a later time, and the newer method is the better way to accomplish the same thing.